# Python imports not working in Visual Studio, Win 10

Tags: python, visual-studio, import, visual-studio-2015, python-3.5

I cannot get certain imports to work in Python, in Visual Studio, on Windows 10. I installed them using the command:

`python -m pip install scikit-learn`

and it says they are saved to:

`c:\users\[My Name]\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages`

However, when I try to use them in the program I get the error:

`Unable to resolve "sklearn". IntelliSense may be missing for this module.`

Originally I thought the problem was because I have two hard drives, but both the Python application and Visual Studio are also saved to the C drive. What should I do from here?

Comment: Is it obligatory to use Visual Studio? You can use Anaconda distribution: https://www.continuum.io/downloads. Such libraries as sklearn, numpy and so on are already in that distribution. You can work on Spyder IDE included in it.

Comment: Yeah, Visual Studio is required.